# Why do physics books perform this "trick" in integration?

Tags: physics

I have the following question, because general physics books like Sears and Serway and others, if not the vast majority, simplify differentials when integrated.
Formally I interpret that this is justified by the first fundamental theorem of calculus, but I'm not sure.
I would appreciate your support, to clarify this doubt, I attach an example.

Let $v=\frac{dr}{dt}$ denote the velocity vector, as let $r$ denote the position vector. Let $F=m\frac{dv}{dt}$ the projection of the net force with the displacement and denote the force at a specified position. Let the mass $m$ be constant. Then the work done along a curve $C$ is defined as,

$$W=\int_{C} F \cdot dr=m \int_{C} \frac{dv}{dt} \cdot dr$$

---

The next steps seem sloppy to me.

$$=m \int_{v_i}^{v_f} \frac{dr}{dt} \cdot \frac {dv} {dr} dr$$
HERE, justification for the "cancellation" of the differential
$$=m \int_{v_i}^{v_f} \frac{dr}{dt} \cdot dv$$
$$=m \int_{v_i}^{v_f} v \cdot dv$$

$$=m \int_{|v_i|}^{|v_f|} |v| \,d|v|$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}m|v_f|^2-\frac{1}{2}m|v_i|^2$$

$$=\Delta \text{KE}$$

Comment: Changing the name of the variable to $r$ and $l$ and back again is messy and requires some justification, but the rest of the argument seems to be the usual change of variables.

Comment: yes. I'm sorry, I put l instead of r, but then it has to do with the variable change method?

Comment: Yes, you can change the variables of integration like this.

Comment: The issue is that $r$ is a vector variable, and we're doing a $t$ integration. I have no idea what $dv/dr$ means.

Comment: This is taking the component of the vector $r$ parallel to the action of the force $F$. The change in velocity is all in this direction. That has not been clearly justified though. But even if you try to justify it like that, then a worse mathematical error is changing the integral from $v$ in the direction of the force to $|v|$ and then inserting those limits of integration using the initial and final velocities. We can justify that using pythagoras, but the way it is posed is specious logic.

Comment: It happens to work because the answer is the square of the velocity, so by coincidence it comes out right.

Answer (score 8):

This makes no sense at all to me. $\vec r$ is a vector variable here, so I have no idea what $\dfrac{d\vec v}{d\vec r}d\vec r$ is supposed to mean. Nor does it make sense for the velocities to become the limits of a $d\vec r$ integration.

It's easy enough to make it correct.
\begin{align*}
\int_C \frac{d\vec v}{dt}\cdot d\vec r &= \int_{t=a}^{t=b} \frac{d\vec v}{dt}\cdot \frac{d\vec r}{dt}dt = \int_{t=a}^{t=b} \frac{d\vec v}{dt}\cdot \vec v\, dt \\
&= \int_{t=a}^{t=b} \frac12 \frac d{dt}\big(\vec v\cdot \vec v\big)\,dt = 
\frac12 \|\vec v\|^2 \Big|_{t=a}^{t=b}.
\end{align*}
The first equality is the definition of the line integral, and the final equality is the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Answer (score 0):

$
\newcommand\diff\underline
\newcommand\adj\overline
\newcommand\DD[2]{\frac{\mathrm d#1}{\mathrm d#2}}
$

We can make this work, though I agree that the way it's presented is very sloppy and perhaps outright wrong.

If $v = v(r(t))$, then by the chain rule
$$
  \DD vt = \diff{v\circ r} = \diff v\circ\diff r = \diff v\left(\DD rt\right)
$$
where $\diff F$ is the total differential of $F$, i.e. the matrix of the linear map $\diff F : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ in the standard basis is the Jacobian matrix. It follows that
$$
  \DD vt\cdot dr = \diff v\left(\DD rt\right)\cdot dr = \DD rt\cdot\adj v(dr)
$$
where $\adj v$ rs the adjoint of $\diff v$ under the inner product. But $\adj v(dr) = dv$, i.e. $\adj v^{-1}$ gives the transformation of $dr$ under the change-of-variables $r \mapsto v(r)$. To be more precise,
$$
  \adj v(dr) := \adj v(w(r))ds = dv
$$
where $w(r)$ is the unit tangent to the curve at $r$ and $ds$ is the scalar arc-length element. So altogether we've shown
$$
  \DD vt\cdot dr = \DD rt\cdot dv.
$$

Comment: There is no way that you can make the final limits of integration argument work though. The component of $v_i$ perpendicular to the initial force only comes out like that due to pythagoras' theorem, which is purely a coincidence because the answer is in $v^2$.

Comment: @SuzuHirose Oh, I absolutely agree, I was just addressing the "cancelling differentials".